# Can not crawl trending topic of twitter

Tags: python, twitter

```
>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
>>> trends = twitter_search.trends()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    trends = twitter_search.trends()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter\api.py", line 173, in __call__
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter\api.py", line 198, in _handle_response
    raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: trends.json using parameters: ()
details: ‹
```

I also try it by changing domain

```
>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_api=twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com", api_version='1')
>>> WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
>>> world_trends = twitter_api.trends._(WORLD_WOE_ID)
>>> [ trend for trend in world_trends()[0]['trends'] ]
[{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%2320CutestFollowers', u'query': u'%2320CutestFollowers', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'#20CutestFollowers'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23watkiestnl', u'query': u'%23watkiestnl', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'#watkiestnl'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23FelizCumplea%C3%B1osAmaia', u'query': u'%23FelizCumplea%C3%B1osAmaia', u'name': u'#FelizCumplea\xf1osAmaia', u'promoted_content': None, u'events': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%22Hi%20Boyfriend%22', u'query': u'%22Hi%20Boyfriend%22', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'Hi Boyfriend'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%22Christina%20Legendtina%20Aguilera%22', u'query': u'%22Christina%20Legendtina%20Aguilera%22', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'Christina Legendtina Aguilera'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%22Jeroen%20Pauw%22', u'query': u'%22Jeroen%20Pauw%22', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'Jeroen Pauw'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=%22Denmark%20Has%20%C3%86bleskiver%20Niall%22', u'query': u'%22Denmark%20Has%20%C3%86bleskiver%20Niall%22', u'name': u'Denmark Has \xc6bleskiver Niall', u'promoted_content': None, u'events': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=Jide', u'query': u'Jide', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'Jide'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=T.O', u'query': u'T.O', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'T.O'}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search/?q=Getafe', u'query': u'Getafe', u'events': None, u'promoted_content': None, u'name': u'Getafe'}]
```

I got the result but I can't understand it. I am new to research work and also new to python and twitterApi.

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand - the list of trends? If so, it's just a list of dictionaries, e.g you could extract the trend names  by doing `[trend['name'] for trend in world_trends()[0]['trends']]`

Comment: no problem! I've answered'ified my comment so the question can be marked as answered \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you had before, but assigning your list-comprehension to `trends`:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_api=twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com", api_version='1')
>>> WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
>>> world_trends = twitter_api.trends._(WORLD_WOE_ID)
>>> trends = [ trend for trend in world_trends()[0]['trends'] ]
```

`trends` is just a list of dictionaries (you can use the [`pprint.pprint`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to print structures like this, to make it easier to read)

To get the trend names, you just need to access the `name` item in each dict, like so:

```
>>> [cur['name'] for cur in trends]
[u'#20CutestFollowers', u'#watkiestnl', ...]
```

Or:

```
for cur in trends:
    print cur['name']
```